# Hadoop Program cannot find installed binary

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have hadoop setup and running on my machine , I am trying to run PEGASUS peta scale mining program , but when I do make , there are lot of warning and following is part of it:

```
13/03/21 12:58:42 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2700(DFSClient.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2826)

13/03/21 12:58:42 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes =
= null
13/03/21 12:58:42 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
13/03/21 12:58:42 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hadoop/hadi_edge/catepillar_star.edge could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2700(DFSClient.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2826)
```

I thought this one is a permission issue then I tried sudo make and then I get the folloing error:

```
Hadoop is not installed in the system.
Please install Hadoop and make sure the hadoop binary is accessible.
make: *** [demo_hadi] Error 127
```

Hadoop is already installed as i print my jps :

```
hadoop@polaris:~/PEGASUS$ jps
7814 JobTracker
8061 TaskTracker
3799 FsShell
7718 SecondaryNameNode
9155 FsShell
8881 RunJar
7235 NameNode
6339 RunJar
9236 Jps
```

Thanks for the time , I really want to know what is going wrong !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As visible, Datanode is not up on your system (Same is the probable reason for "could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1")

It happens sometimes.

Solution : Stop all the hadoop daemons and start them again. Look if all the 5 daemons are running (namenode, Secondary namenode,datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker).

Try running some sample code to test that framework is running fine.

Restart the machine, if the above solution isnt working.

If issue persists, reformat the namenode (not a very good advise though; should be kept as last solution).

Comment: I tried ./stop-all.sh and then ./start-all.sh , again same stack trace is generated

Comment: Problem, as i told, is that the datanode is not up. Please check if you have installed Hadoop correctly. Check whether conf files have been modified correctly.

Comment: ok , I did rm -rf on app/tmp/hadoop/tmp and started again it works fine now , thanks

Comment: could you explain why do we need to delete tmp/ to start datanode again

Comment: The reason for this is explained in http://serverfault.com/questions/403150/hadoop-datanode-is-giving-me-an-incompatible-namespace-id and http://blog.abhinavmathur.net/2013/01/experience-from-last-posts-hadoop-setup.html